# Why can't I connect to my Pi via VNC?

Tags: ssh, vnc, macos

I have installed TightVNC on my Pi. I can SSH into the Pi just fine and start the server successfully. But then I can't seem to connect to it using a viewer. I am on OSX, so I've tried using the Java viewer that TightVNC supplies. I enter the IP and use the default port of 5900. It times out. I try using SSH tunnelling. It gets stuck on handshaking. I've also tried the RealVNC viewer but that likewise can't seem to connect. What else can I try?

Comment: Assuming you have installed `tightvncserver` on the Pi and started it you should be able to connect from the Mac with `open vnc://pi@IP.local:5901`. You don't need any viewer. If you need help you have to tell us WHAT YOU DID, not that it doesn't work.

Comment: @Milliways The first line of my question says 'I have installed TightVNC on my Pi. I can SSH into the Pi just fine and start the server successfully.' - don't know if I can say much more than that. When I tried your suggestion of 'open vnc://' etc it failed again. 'Unable to communicate with <ip>'

Comment: Should be `open vnc://pi@IP:5901` (I cut and paste from my code which doesn't use IP). What happens when you run `tightvncserver` on the Pi - past the output the Pi produces.

Comment: Yeah, I added in the appropriate IP. When I run `tightvncserver` it outputs `New 'X' desktop is raspberrypi:2`

Comment: I never understand why people ask for help, but fail to answer questions. Post the EXACT commands you enter and the OUTPUT. You now have 2 instances of tightvncserver running so port becomes 5902 etc.

Comment: That is the exact command I used. `tightvncserver`. That's it. And that is the only output I get, other than `Starting applications specified in /home/pi/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/pi/.vnc/raspberrypi:2.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue using TightVNC's Java viewer, which allows SSH tunnelling. Using that option I entered the SSH host address as 127.0.0.1 and the port to 5901 (corresponding to the :1 instance of the server), and the SSH tunnel to the actual IP of the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

I found an issue related to this discussion that I couldn't find anywhere else. I just spent a couple hours trying to get my VNC connection to work and finally found that I needed to add the following to /etc/iptables.firewall.rules and restart:

```
# Allow VNC
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5901  -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the attached image (this worked for me -- thanks!) [image]

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Or add to the above answer?

Comment: This does not contribute anything further that I can see, I'd be tempted to -1 this but I have refrained in the hope that the contributor can add something constructive: e.g. what else did they try that didn't work (so that others can see why @user8543 answer - which has been reproduced visually here - is the only or the best solution)...

Answer (score 0):

I am also using TightVNC as the Viewer, but using Bitvise for SSH, and the original RealVNC Server on the Pi.  Trying to login to 127.0.0.1:5900 I was able to get a  connection, but the login would fail.  There seems to be a problem with Loopback connections not being allowed, by my SSH client.  I set Bitvise to use port 59000 to destination port 5900.  Then use TightVNC client to connect to 127.0.0.1:59000.  Login was successful after that.  I think that the solution above where the user used TightVNC's Java Viewer worked because that would also evade and avoid the Loopback issue.